# How to display a list of all users in a provider-hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm making a provider-hosted app for SharePoint on Office 365 and I need to display a list of the users within a site collection. Can anyone point me in the right direction with some code? Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sharepoint client object model to display the list.

Sample code:

```
var targetSite = new Uri("site");
            var login = "username";
            var password = "password";
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetSite))
            {


                clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                UserCollection users = web.SiteUsers;
                clientContext.Load(users);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach(User user in users)
                {
                    string username = user.Email;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SharePoint Online Management Shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to remotely manage users and groups in SharePoint Online.

[Get-SPOUser cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161389%28v=office.15%29.aspx) returns the SharePoint Online user or security group accounts that match a given search criteria, for example:

```
Get-SPOUser -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/finance
```

returns all user or security group accounts from the site collection `http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/finance`

---

In addition, SharePoint API provides [Web.SiteUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.siteusers%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to get the collection of all users that belong to the site collection

REST endpoint example:

```
http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/finance/_api/web/SiteUsers
```

JSOM example:

```
(function(){ 

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var siteUsers = context.get_web().get_siteUsers();

context.load(siteUsers);    
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
      //print site users 
      for (var i = 0; i < siteUsers.get_count(); i++) {
            var siteUser = siteUsers.getItemAtIndex(i);
            console.log(siteUser.get_title());
      }  
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);

})();
```